# Function heightForRowAt gets called only once in connection with UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var secondRunSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func secondRunToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        
        secondTimerActiveLabel.textColor = (secondRunSwitch.isOn ? .black : .gray)
        
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        switch indexPath {
        case IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1):
            return secondRunSwitch.isOn ? 44 : 0
        case IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1):
            return secondRunSwitch.isOn ? 44 : 0
        default:
            return 44
        }
    }
```

The plan here is to hide/show static tableView cells whether switch is toggled off/on.

These cells hide after toggling off the switch for the first time, but does not show up after toggling it back on.

Where's the catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show/hide a cell by returning different values from the `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` and `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` table view data source methods.

Which are called when you invoke:

```
    let section = 0
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: section), with: .automatic)
```